# How to properly drive in puddles of water

Tags: car

I just had a question. I live in California, so it doesn’t rain that often, so when it does, I get a little anxious simply because I’m not quite used to it. I’ve heard a lot of different theories on how to drive your car through a puddle.. I’ve heard you should keep the brake pushed a little bit, to speed up, to slow down, & to swerve your tires back and forth (?) I’ve only tried speeding up because the seems the most sensible thing to me. So, please, enlighten, educate, share wisdom with me on how to drive my car through a puddle. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: As @Solar Mike said, avoid hitting puddles with high speed as it can cause aqua-planing causing you to lose control. Also, you can never know how deep a puddle is, so it might be a big pot hole.. damaging your vehicle. Other than that, at speeds like ~50kmh, I don't see anything going wrong, but try to avoid them. Do not swerve in to upcoming traffic, or cause any danger to anyone else..

Comment: Related: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/21793/12030

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to get closed,

But try to avoid puddles - does not mean swerve into oncoming traffic...

Slow down as the puddle only hitting one side can drag you left or right depending, also aqua-planing can be a possibility where the tires become waterlogged and you loose control (steering and braking).