# Water damage underneath a car?

Tags: repair

I recently ran through a puddle a couple of days a ago. The puddle wasn’t too deep, but I was going at least 40 in 30, but every time I make a turn, it sounds like a cranking or grinding sound now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, slow down, especially for puddles... Check for any baffles or guards that may have been bent. Read this post (one example, there are others on here about hitting water...) and its answers : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/21791/10976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a grinding sound then it's either directly related to the puddle or a coincidence. If it's directly related what is most likely happening is that a cover, piece of trim or a body panel has come loose or gotten bent and is rubbing against one of the tires. Another possibility is that debris floating in the puddle got sucked up into a front wheel well.

First isolate the side of the car the sound is coming from, then look at that wheel well, it will probably be pretty apparent what's causing it. If it's debris then clear it, if it's loose or bent trim it may be as simple as pushing it back into place and refitting a push connector, or it may need some sort of replacement parts, it's hard to say. I'd get the wheel off and inspect that as well, if something sharp has cut into the sidewall then it will weaken your tire and it could blow at the worst possible point.

It's possible that the water knocked something loose in the engine bay and its is now rubbing on a moving part when you're turning, get a flashlight and have a really good look near anything that spins like pulleys, belts and fans.

Other causes of grinding when turning would be a failing CV joint (possibly caused by water getting in through bad CV boots, but unlikely to happen that quickly), brake problems or an issue in your power steering system. These are unlikely to be caused by a puddle (unless a brake has sucked in a pebble or other debris), so more likely a coincidence, which can happen.

Comment: I saw a bent part the day after that’s sticking out from my car that looks like it’s hitting against my wheel. It looks like the best way would be to trim it. But my friend is going to come over to check everything else out just to make sure. Everything you said sounded like every possible situation. Thanks. I’m not going to lie. I don’t know too much about cars, but your info helped me a lot. :)

Comment: Glad it was helpful @EnvyAdams. I would think hard before trimming anything, if the part is there chances are it's for a reason, and cutting it could have detrimental effects. Best find a way to fix it.

Comment: It’s really bent though @GdD. But like I said, my friend is coming by to take a look and look at it and see if they can fix it. If you were to look at my car from the back, you could see the part sticking out from where the wheel is. It’s bad...

Answer (score 0):

I once hit a deep puddle at high speed in the dark, I didn't see it till just before I hit it

It tore the heat shield off the catalytic converter and I could hear this scraping on the ground afterwards. could be something similar